# Find the most common element in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, counter

This is my list

```
a=[ ['a','b','a','a'],
    ['c','c','c','d','d','d']]
```

I wanna find most common elemments.
I have tried this

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['hello', 'hell', 'owl', 'hello', 'world', 'war', 'hello', 
         'war','aa','aa','aa','aa']

counter_obj = Counter(words)

counter_obj.most_common()
```

but it works just for simple list.
my output should be like this

```
[('a', 3), ('c', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 1)]
```

Comment: So, what is the expected output for `a=[['a','b','a','a'],['c','c','c','d','d','d']]`?

Comment: In your list "a" what do you want to find as most common? the inner elements like 'a' or 'c' or the list elements of the outer list, like ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `Counter().update()` option on the elements of your list,
Based on suggestion from @BlueSheepToken

```
from collections import Counter

words = [['a','b','a','a'],['c','c','c','d','d','d']]
counter = Counter(words[0])
for i in words[1:]: 
    counter.update(i)

counter.most_common()
```

output:

```
[('a', 3), ('c', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 1)]
```

Comment: @aaaa you havn't told us what is the correct output for this example

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: what you have inserted as output is ok. but when i run your code it gives me wrong answer.

Comment: For performance, you should avoid using the `extend` method but you should use the `update` method from the `Counter` class

Comment: For performance, you should avoid an explicit `for` loop altogether. You can chain lists lazily and feed an iterable of lists to `Couter`.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

`collections.Counter` accepts any iterable of hashable elements. So you can chain your list of lists via `itertools.chain`. The benefit of this solution is it works for any number of sublists.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counter_obj = Counter(chain.from_iterable(a))

print(counter_obj.most_common())

[('a', 3), ('c', 3), ('d', 3), ('b', 1)]
```