# How to Find Common Keys in an Array of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

Given an array of dictionaries: [{'key1': 'valueA', 'key2': 'valueB'}, {'key1': 'valueC', 'key3': 'valueD'}, {}, ... ]

How would you find the most common keys among the dictionaries and rank them?

In this example the key of 'key1' appears twice, so this would be ranked number 1. Then if 'key2' would appear with the next common frequency, this would be ranked number 2, and so on.

Comment: what have you tried so far to achieve the motive?

Comment: asking for the most common keys means deciding on a threshold s such that: if the key k appears more than s times, then k is common. From what you write it looks like you only want to order the keys according to frequency since you do not provide any definition of "most common keys".

Comment: I noticed a downvote so I'm afraid you are going to be shot down, but don't take it personally. They are looking for some sign of efforts. This can probably be reduced to finding the common elements in a list of lists (where `.keys()` for each dictionary are the sub lists). That question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515649/find-the-most-common-element-in-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

**Code Syntax**

```
dicts =[{'key1': 'valueA', 'key2': 'valueB'}, {'key1': 'valueC', 'key3': 'valueD'}]

lis = [list(dicts[i].keys()) for i in range(len(dicts))]
x = sorted([j for i in lis for j in i])
print(x)
for i, each in enumerate(x):
    if x[i-1] == x[i]:
        continue
    else:
        indey = x.count(x[x.index(each)])
        print(f"{each} = {indey}")
```

**Output**

```
['key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']
key1 = 2
key2 = 1
key3 = 1

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
keys = dict()
# d is your dictionary
for i in d:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k in keys:
            keys[k] += 1
        else:
            keys[k] = 1
max = 0
max_key = ''
for k, v in keys.items():
    if v > max:
        max = v
        max_key = k
print(max, max_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for that to [parse the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638258/2402281) and then [describe it to get stats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html#pandas-dataframe-describe).

```
import pandas as pd

lod = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'month': 'june'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(lod)

print(df.describe(include=['float', 'object']))

'''
           points  time    year    month  points_h1
count    3.000000     3     1.0        3        1.0
unique        NaN     3     NaN        3        NaN
top           NaN  9:00     NaN  january        NaN
freq          NaN     1     NaN        1        NaN
mean    55.000000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
std     32.787193   NaN     NaN      NaN        NaN
min     25.000000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
25%     37.500000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
50%     50.000000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
75%     70.000000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
max     90.000000   NaN  2010.0      NaN       20.0
'''
```

Note however that this does not work with nested dictionaries! And you need to install `pandas` with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

is that your answer

```
from collections import Counter
d=[{'key1': 'valueA', 'key2': 'valueB'}, {'key1': 'valueC', 'key3': 'valueD'}, {'key1': 'valueC'}]
keys=[]
for i in d:
    for j in i.keys():
        keys.append(j)
        
Counter(keys)
```

output

```
Counter({'key1': 3, 'key2': 1, 'key3': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count that:

```py
import collections

def count(array):
    counter = collections.Counter()
    for dict in array:
        counter.update(dict.keys())
    return counter

print(count([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}])) # Counter({'a': 2})
print(count([{'f': 2}, {'f': '2'}, {'b': 10}])) # Counter({'f': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nice solution using `pandas` would be to convert the dictionaries in dataframes, merge them and then use `value_counts`. Here is a little example

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'key1': '1', 'key2': '2'}
d2 = {'key1': '1', 'key3': '3'}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1.items())
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2.items())

frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
print(result[0].value_counts())
```

Which prints

```
key1    2
key2    1
key3    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Extract the keys in a flat list
keys = [k for k, v in i.items for i in data]

# Sort and group
from itertools import sorted, groupby
s = sorted(keys)
g = groupby(s)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
d=[{'key1': 'valueA', 'key2': 'valueB'}, {'key1': 'valueC', 'key3': 'valueD'}, {} ]
c = Counter(key for t in d for key in t.keys())
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({'key1': 2, 'key2': 1, 'key3': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this, I assume one of the cleanest ways would be to use the Counter class, however I would do it the following way:

```
my_dicts = [{"hello": 2},{"hello1": 3, "hello": 5},{"hello2": 5, "hello": 7, "hello1": 4}]


merged = {}
for d in my_dicts:
  for k in d.keys():
    if k in merged:
      merged[k] += 1
    else:
      merged[k] = 1
results = {k: v for k, v in sorted(merged.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)}
```

The variable `results` ends up containing a dictionary of the sorted items in descending order, like such:

Output:

```
{'hello': 3, 'hello1': 2, 'hello2': 1}
```